# Scribe for FB Oauth - Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Tags: facebook, oauth, scribe

I am trying to use [scribe](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started) for Facebook OAuth 2.0 implementation and I get below error

> '{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make
>   sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth
>   dialog
>   request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"FusY4X0TorE"}}'

I used the below URL to get Token

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?granted_scopes=1&response_type=code&client_id=473486006089780&scope=email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location&redirect_uri=https://www.bankbazaar.com/

I create my service as below

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                .apiKey("1415540682058832")
                .apiSecret("07b182efcb587065ceef615a945d92a4")
                .callback("https://www.bankbazaar.com/")
                .build();
```

Let's say I get valid code/verifier from FB and use it to get access token

I print my Authorization URL and get something as below

https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1415540682058832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bankbazaar.com%2F

In my Facebook App page, I have the below setting
[image]

Kindly suggest where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set redirect URL in `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`. It is in `Settings` -> `Advanced`, scroll down to `Client OAuth Settings`-> `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`:

[image]

Comment: I set it like that, but its not working. Should it be strictly "http"? Cos i am using "http".